# Use value from hiera hash in Yaml

Tags: puppet, hiera

In Hiera (Puppet 4.10), I have a YAML entry that looks like this:

```
xyz::some_name: "%{hiera('abc::query')}"
```

where the result of `hiera('abc::query')` is a single-element array containing  a hash with one value in it:

```
[{data => some_value}]
```

What I want to do is set `some_name` to `some_value`.

I have tried

```
xyz::some_name: "%{hiera('abc::query.0.data')}"
```

and

```
xyz::some_name: "%{hiera('abc::query')[0][data]}"
```

(I can use the latter form, as `${hiera('abc::query')[0][data]}` in a Puppet manifest just fine)

What's the correct way to index into a hiera lookup in a YAML file ?

Comment: Are you using Hiera 3 or Hiera 5?  I don't believe the former supports key.subkey notation.

Comment: If you are using Hiera 5, then you should try quoting the key: `"%{lookup('\"abc::query\".0.data')}"`.  You'll see that I also switched to the `lookup()` function, though I *think* the behavior should be the same as with `hiera()`.

Comment: Ah well that explains why I can't get it to work. My hiera version is 3.3.2 and my Puppet version is 4.10.6. I did try what you suggested and it didn't work. But thank you. I naively assumed I'd have hiera 5 because I have Puppet 4.10.

Comment: You do have Hiera 5 with Puppet 4.10. Hiera 5 is just deployed as part of the Puppet gem. If you have the older Hiera 3 installed alongside Hiera 5 within Puppet, then you must be installing with something other than the AIO. This is fine, but just be aware that is why you came to the incorrect conclusion.